# show FC error when use OnClickListiner in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want use `Button` to use Layout, whe use `OnCLickListener` method show me FC error. use this code in `Fragment`. 
My `Fragment` code :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsms_card_fragment, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.newSMS_recycler);
        context = view.getContext();

        b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

show error this line :

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Logcat error :

```
10-13 10:07:22.126  21653-21653/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tellfa.smsbox, PID: 21653
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.tellfa.smsbox.fragments.Fragment_newSMS.onCreateView(Fragment_newSMS.java:66)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

newsms_card_fragment xml code :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/newSMS_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

newsms_card_layout xml code : 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_bg">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_l"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newSMS_username_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="نام کاربری جوووووون"
                android:textColor="#8c8c8c"
                android:textSize="23sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_l"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="#808c8c8c" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_bg_2"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/users_avatar"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/all_users_avatar"
        app:civ_border_color="#8c8c8c"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newSMS_like_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newSMS_count_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newSMS_category_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newSMS_Date_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newSMS_hour_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sms_newsms_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you help me too fix it? tnx all dears <3

Comment: is `newsms_card_fragment` contains `button b2` ?

Comment: Add your layout file in newsms_card_fragment

Comment: @MD, No. `newsms_card_fragment` contains `RecyclerView` and use adapter to set `CardCiew`, in `newsms_card_fragment`. Button b2 there are `newsms_card_layout`

Comment: That's why you got NPE...

Comment: @Sunny, update this post please

Comment: @AmitBasliyal, update this post please

Comment: @ydstsh please try blow code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Fragment` contains `newsms_card_fragment.xml` as a view, which has only one child i.e `RecyclerView`. 
You should inflate the `RecyclerView` with its `RecyclerViewAdapter` having `ViewHolder` with `newsms_card_layout` as xml.
Then in adapter of the `RecyclerView` you can implement code for button `OnClickListener`.

For more information, How to get started with [RecyclerView](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/).

Answer (score 1):

In newsms_card_fragment.xml have only RecyclerView which is similar to listview. This Layout doesn't have any button and remove this lines

```
b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i need this line and button. how to use it?

Comment: Then u need to add this button in ur xml..   <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />        ..... Please mark as correct and upvote if u get what u want

Answer (score 1):

*Please implement OnClickListener*

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsms_card_fragment, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.newSMS_recycler);
    context = view.getContext();

    b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
public void onClick(View view) {
 // code 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling findViewById on a view that does not exist yet. You need to inflate the layout that you want and then you can call the findViewById. Try the following code.

```
View b2Layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.<b2s layout name>, null);
Button b1 = (Button)b2Layout.findViewById(R.id.b2);
```